# Wireguard selective routing

Tags: networking, debian, wireguard

learning linux.

I have a NAS on debian OMW6 in my home LAN (which is hidden behind a NAT), and I also have a VDS with a wireguard server. I want to have access to my NAS outside of my LAN, but I also want the NAS not to use tunnel by default.

if you up the client interface on NAS via wg-quick, then all traffic is wrapped through the tunnel, but I want the traffic to be wrapped only if the destination ip is 10.8.0.X (wireguard local area network).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WireGuard on Linux uses regular routing through a virtual interface (like most other tunnel types except for IPsec) – if your routing table says packets go through wg0, then they go through wg0.

By default, wg-quick installs kernel routes **according to your AllowedIPs** (WireGuard internal routes), as this setting also affects peer selection for outbound packets (not only filtering of inbound ones) and in most cases it would be pointless to have AllowedIPs that weren't routed through the interface.

For example, if your tunnel interface has `AllowedIPs = ::/0` for a specific peer, then wg-quick will accordingly install a `::/0 dev wg0` kernel route through the tunnel.

There are several ways to avoid this:

- If you only want to route specific destinations, only include those destinations in AllowedIPs, e.g. if you only allow `10.8.0.0/24` for the [Peer] entry of your VPS, then that's what wg-quick will add as a kernel route as well.
- If you don't want any automatic routes from AllowedIPs, specify `Table = off` in the global [Interface] section. The kernel will still add "local" routes from your own IP address, so if you have `Address = 10.8.0.55/24` in the [Interface] section, then the kernel will add a route `10.8.0.0/24 dev wg0` but wg-quick won't add anything extra.

  "Table = off" is already the default in systemd-networkd.
- If you want to route all destinations according to some other criteria (e.g. only for packets with a specific TCP port or iptables mark), specify a custom routing table number as `Table = 123`, then use `ip -4 rule` and `ip -6 rule` to create rules matching your criteria and selecting that routing table, e.g.:

  ```
  PostUp = ip -4 rule add from 192.168.1.7 lookup 123
  ```

Comment: tnx! im write [Peer] AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.0/24 in client config file and its work just like i want